# Is it possible to bind XAML/C# with HTML using PHP?

Tags: c#, php, html, xaml

So I have a XAML button:

```
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Version, ElementName=Control}"  />
<Button Content="Support" Width="100" Click="HelpSupport_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Which links to some C#

```
 private void HelpSupport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("support.html");
    }
```

Which takes a user to a webpage.
In my XAML StackPanel above I'm binding the software version into a text block for the user to see. But my question is, is it possible that when the user clicks the button to go to the website, can I somehow bind the text block data to be transferred into the HTML too? So that when the user gets to the webpage the software version is also showing there too? Just wondering if this would be done via PHP or a JSON call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it, these are the changes made:

```
private void HelpSupport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("support.php?version=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Version.ToString()));
    }
```

Which put the number in the URL. So my output in HTML:

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="es_version" >
<?php   echo  $_GET["version"]; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of recent experience with HTML and PHP, but if my memory doesn't fail me, you could add the text of the TextBlock as a variable at the end of the URL of the webpage (it would look like this `www.webpage.com?text=version`) and then from PHP use the GET method to get the value of the variable `text` in your URL.

You can do this with more than one variable, like this `www.webpage.com?text=version&var2=hello`

Comment: Sorry, but now that I think about it, my anser might not be usefull since you are starting the webpage from a file.

Comment: no the webpage is hosted, I just cut the URL out of the code. But yes someone did mention about putting the number in the URL like you said, which is sort of what I had in mind but wasn't sure how it would work